# Why does unequipping this tool relocates the player to the center of the map in Roblox?

Tags: lua, scripting, roblox

This gear was inserted from the Catalog. It relocates the player to the center of the map when it's unequipped by clicking on the thumbnail. At 1st, I tested in a game I made. Everytime I unequipped it, the player kept falling through the baseplate and dying. I noticed it is the same position over and over. I moved the baseplate's position lower and the player falls down onto the baseplate instead of dying. Then I tested the gear in a new empty baseplate, unequipping it, the player moves to the center, too. I check the position of the both the Handle and the player's Torso, but that axis does not match any position in the script. Can someone point this out for me so that I can change it to the last position that the player stops?

```
Tool = script.Parent
Handle = Tool:WaitForChild("Handle")
Players = game:GetService("Players")
Debris = game:GetService("Debris")
Assets = require(Tool:WaitForChild("Assets"))
Data = Assets.Data
BaseUrl = Assets.BaseUrl
BasePart = Instance.new("Part")
BasePart.Material = Enum.Material.Plastic
BasePart.Shape = Enum.PartType.Block
BasePart.TopSurface = Enum.SurfaceType.Smooth
BasePart.BottomSurface = Enum.SurfaceType.Smooth
BasePart.FormFactor = Enum.FormFactor.Custom
BasePart.Size = Vector3.new(0.2, 0.2, 0.2)
BasePart.Anchored = false
BasePart.CanCollide = true
BasePart.Locked = true
Animations = {
Hold = {Animation = Tool:WaitForChild("Hold"), FadeTime = nil, Weight = nil, Speed = nil}
}
Sounds = {
Honk = Handle:WaitForChild("Honk"),
Engine = Handle:WaitForChild("Running")
}
Controls = {
Forward = {Key = "w", ByteKey = 17, Mode = false},
Backward = {Key = "s", ByteKey = 18, Mode = false},
Left = {Key = "a", ByteKey = 20, Mode = false},
Right = {Key = "d", ByteKey = 19, Mode = false}
}
Rate = (1 / 60)
Gravity = 196.20
PoseOffset = CFrame.new(0, -1.5125, -0.3) * CFrame.Angles(0, 0, 0) --The offset your character is from the center of the vehicle.
SpeedBoost = {
Allowed = false,
Active = false,
Enabled = true,
Duration = 10,
ReloadTime = 30
}
Special = {
Allowed = false,
Enabled = true,
Active = false,
Duration = 0,
ReloadTime = 60
}
Speed = {
Acceleration = {
Normal = 30,
Boost = 30
},
Deceleration = {
Normal = 30,
Boost = 30
},
MovementSpeed = {
Normal = {Min = 20, Max = 70},
Boost = {Min = 20, Max = 70}
},
TurnSpeed = {
Speed = {Min = 5, Max = 5},
TurnAlpha = 0.30,
AlphaDampening = 0.2
},
}
MaxSpeed = { --Maximum speed which the vehicle can move and turn at.
Movement = Speed.MovementSpeed.Normal,
Turn = Speed.TurnSpeed.Speed,
Acceleration = Speed.Acceleration.Normal,
Deceleration = Speed.Deceleration.Normal
}
CurrentSpeed = { --The speed which the vehicle is moving and turning at.
Movement = 0,
Turn = 0
}
Honk = {
Honking = false,
LastHonk = 0,
ReloadTime = 1
}
Jump = {
Jumping = false,
LastJump = 0,
ReloadTime = 1.25,
JumpForce = 30
}
ToolEquipped = false
ServerControl = (Tool:FindFirstChild("ServerControl") or Instance.new("RemoteFunction"))
ServerControl.Name = "ServerControl"
ServerControl.Parent = Tool
ClientControl = (Tool:FindFirstChild("ClientControl") or Instance.new("RemoteFunction"))
ClientControl.Name = "ClientControl"
ClientControl.Parent = Tool
Tool.Enabled = true
function RayCast(Position, Direction, MaxDistance, IgnoreList)
local IgnoreList = ((type(IgnoreList) == "table" and IgnoreList) or {IgnoreList})
return game:GetService("Workspace"):FindPartOnRayWithIgnoreList(Ray.new(Position, Direction.unit * (MaxDistance or 999.999)), IgnoreList)
end
function GetAllConnectedParts(Object)
local Parts = {}
local function GetConnectedParts(Object)
for i, v in pairs(Object:GetConnectedParts()) do
local Ignore = false
for ii, vv in pairs(Parts) do
if v == vv then
Ignore = true
end
end
if not Ignore then
table.insert(Parts, v)
GetConnectedParts(v)
end
end
end
GetConnectedParts(Object)
return Parts
end
function EnableFirstPersonView()
if not CheckIfAlive() or not ToolEquipped then
return
end
local Limbs = {"LeftHand", "RightHand"}
for i, v in pairs(Limbs) do
local Limb = Character:FindFirstChild(v)
if Limb:IsA("BasePart") then
Spawn(function()
InvokeClient("SetLocalTransparencyModifier", {Object = Limb, Transparency = 0, AutoUpdate = false})
end)
end
end
end
function ThrustUpdater()
for i, v in pairs(CurrentSpeed) do
CurrentSpeed[i] = 0
end
for i, v in pairs(Controls) do
Controls[i].Mode = false
end
while ToolEquipped and Body and Body.Parent and CheckIfAlive() and RotationForce and RotationForce.Parent and ThrustForce and ThrustForce.Parent and TurnGyro and TurnGyro.Parent do
RotationForce.angularvelocity = Vector3.new(0, CurrentSpeed.Turn, 0)
if math.abs(CurrentSpeed.Turn) > Speed.TurnSpeed.AlphaDampening then
CurrentSpeed.Turn = (CurrentSpeed.Turn - (Speed.TurnSpeed.AlphaDampening * (math.abs(CurrentSpeed.Turn) / CurrentSpeed.Turn)))
else
CurrentSpeed.Turn = 0
end
if not Controls.Forward.Mode or Controls.Backward.Mode then --Slow down if not controlling.
CurrentSpeed.Movement = (CurrentSpeed.Movement * 0.99)
end
local MySpeed = Vector3.new(Body.Velocity.X, 0, Body.Velocity.Z).magnitude
local VelocityDifference = math.abs((MySpeed - (ThrustForce.velocity.magnitude)))
if MySpeed > 3 and ThrustForce.velocity.magnitude > 3 and VelocityDifference > (0.7 * ThrustForce.velocity.magnitude) then
CurrentSpeed.Movement = (CurrentSpeed.Movement * 0.9)
end
if Controls.Forward.Mode then --Handle acceleration
CurrentSpeed.Movement = math.min(MaxSpeed.Movement.Max, (CurrentSpeed.Movement + (MaxSpeed.Acceleration * Rate)))
end
if Controls.Backward.Mode then --Handle deceleration, if speed is more than 0, decrease quicker.
CurrentSpeed.Movement = math.max(-MaxSpeed.Movement.Min, (CurrentSpeed.Movement - (MaxSpeed.Deceleration * ((CurrentSpeed.Movement > 0 and 2.8) or 1) * Rate)))
end
if Controls.Left.Mode then --Handle left turn speed
CurrentSpeed.Turn = math.min(Speed.TurnSpeed.Speed.Max, (CurrentSpeed.Turn + (Speed.TurnSpeed.TurnAlpha)))
end
if Controls.Right.Mode then --Handle right turn speed
CurrentSpeed.Turn = math.max(-Speed.TurnSpeed.Speed.Min, (CurrentSpeed.Turn - (Speed.TurnSpeed.TurnAlpha)))
end
local Direction = UpperTorso.CFrame.lookVector
Direction = Vector3.new(Direction.x, 0, Direction.z).unit
local Velocity = (Direction * CurrentSpeed.Movement) --The thrust force which you move.
ThrustForce.velocity = Vector3.new(Velocity.X, ThrustForce.velocity.Y, Velocity.Z)
local LeanAmount = (-CurrentSpeed.Turn * (math.pi / 6) / 4) --Amount your character leans over.
local XZAngle = math.atan2(UpperTorso.CFrame.lookVector.z, 0, UpperTorso.CFrame.lookVector.x) --Handle rotation
TurnGyro.cframe = CFrame.Angles((LeanAmount * Direction.x), 0, (LeanAmount * Direction.z))
--Wheel animation
local DesiredAngle = (999999999 * (-CurrentSpeed.Movement / math.abs(CurrentSpeed.Movement)))
local MaxVelocity = (CurrentSpeed.Movement / 250)
for i, v in pairs({FrontMotor, BackMotor}) do
if v and v.Parent then
v.DesiredAngle = DesiredAngle
v.MaxVelocity = MaxVelocity
end
end
--Smoke exhaust from vehicle running.
for i, v in pairs(ExhaustSmoke) do
if v and v.Parent then
v.Opacity = ((math.min(math.abs(CurrentSpeed.Movement), 10) / 10) * 0.5)
end
end
--Engine running sound which pitch changes while in motion.
Sounds.Engine.Pitch = (1 + (math.abs(CurrentSpeed.Movement / MaxSpeed.Movement.Max) * 1))
wait(Rate)
end
end
function SpawnVehicle()
Handle.Transparency = 1
Spawn(function()
InvokeClient("PlaySound", Sounds.Engine)
InvokeClient("PlayAnimation", Animations.Hold)
end)
Humanoid.PlatformStand = true
local VehicleData = Assets.CreateVehicle()
Body = VehicleData.Vehicle
local ParticleTable = VehicleData.Tables
--FrontMotor = Body.FrontMotor
--BackMotor = Body.BackMotor
ExhaustSmoke = ParticleTable.ExhaustSmoke
Lights = ParticleTable.Lights
Sparkles = ParticleTable.Sparkles
if SpeedBoost.Active then
for i, v in pairs(Sparkles) do
if v and v.Parent then
v.Enabled = true
end
end
end
local UpperTorsoWeld = Instance.new("Weld")
UpperTorsoWeld.C0 = PoseOffset
UpperTorsoWeld.Part0 = UpperTorso
UpperTorsoWeld.Part1 = Body
UpperTorsoWeld.Parent = Body
Body.CanCollide = true
RotationForce = Instance.new("BodyAngularVelocity")
RotationForce.maxTorque = Vector3.new(0, math.huge, 0)
RotationForce.angularvelocity = Vector3.new(0, 0, 0)
RotationForce.Parent = UpperTorso
ThrustForce = Instance.new("BodyVelocity")
ThrustForce.maxForce = Vector3.new(math.huge, 0, math.huge)
ThrustForce.velocity = Vector3.new(0, 0, 0)
ThrustForce.P = 100
ThrustForce.Parent = UpperTorso
TurnGyro = Instance.new("BodyGyro")
TurnGyro.maxTorque = Vector3.new(5000, 0, 5000)
TurnGyro.P = 300
TurnGyro.D = 100
TurnGyro.Parent = UpperTorso
Body.Parent = Tool
local RayHit, RayPos, RayNormal = RayCast(UpperTorso.Position, Vector3.new(0, -1, 0), (UpperTorso.Size.Y * 2), {Character})
if RayHit then
UpperTorso.CFrame = UpperTorso.CFrame + Vector3.new(0, ((Character:GetModelSize().Y / 2) + 1.5), 0)
end
Spawn(ThrustUpdater)
end
function FreezePlayer()
if CheckIfAlive() then
local FreezePart = BasePart:Clone()
FreezePart.Name = "FreezePart"
FreezePart.Transparency = 1
FreezePart.Anchored = true
FreezePart.CanCollide = false
local FreezeWeld = Instance.new("Weld")
FreezeWeld.Part0 = UpperTorso
FreezeWeld.Part1 = FreezePart
FreezeWeld.Parent = FreezePart
Debris:AddItem(FreezePart, 0.125)
FreezePart.Parent = Character
UpperTorso.Velocity = Vector3.new(0, -25, 0)
UpperTorso.RotVelocity = Vector3.new(0, 0, 0)
end
end
function CleanUp()
Handle.Velocity = Vector3.new(0, 0, 0)
Handle.RotVelocity = Vector3.new(0, 0, 0)
for i, v in pairs({}) do
if v then
v:disconnect()
end
end
for i, v in pairs({Body, RotationForce, ThrustForce, TurnGyro}) do
if v and v.Parent then
v:Destroy()
end
end
for i, v in pairs(Tool:GetChildren()) do
if v:IsA("BasePart") and v ~= Handle then
v:Destroy()
end
end
end
function CheckIfAlive()
return (((Character and Character.Parent and Humanoid and Humanoid.Parent and Humanoid.Health > 0 and UpperTorso and UpperTorso.Parent and Player and Player.Parent) and true) or false)
end
function Equipped(Mouse)
Character = Tool.Parent
Player = Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(Character)
Humanoid = Character:FindFirstChild("Humanoid")
UpperTorso = Character:FindFirstChild("UpperTorso")
if not CheckIfAlive() then
return
end
Spawn(CleanUp)
Spawn(EnableFirstPersonView)
Spawn(SpawnVehicle)
ToolEquipped = true
end
function Unequipped()
Spawn(CleanUp)
Spawn(FreezePlayer)
for i, v in pairs(Sounds) do
v:Stop()
Spawn(function()
InvokeClient("StopSound", v)
end)
end
if CheckIfAlive() then
Humanoid.PlatformStand = false
end
Handle.Transparency = 0
ToolEquipped = false
end
function OnServerInvoke(player, mode, value)
if player == Player and ToolEquipped and value and CheckIfAlive() then
if mode == "KeyPress" then
local Down = value.Down
local Key = value.Key
local ByteKey = string.byte(Key)
for i, v in pairs(Controls) do
if Key == v.Key or ByteKey == v.ByteKey then
Controls[i].Mode = Down
end
end
if Key == " " and Down then --Jump controller
if math.abs(tick() - Jump.LastJump) > Jump.ReloadTime and not Jump.Jumping and ThrustForce and ThrustForce.Parent then
Jump.Jumping = true
local Parts = GetAllConnectedParts(Body)
local Mass = 0
for i, v in pairs(Parts) do
Mass = (Mass + v:GetMass())
end
ThrustForce.maxForce = Vector3.new(ThrustForce.maxForce.X, ((Mass * Gravity) * 100), ThrustForce.maxForce.Z)
ThrustForce.velocity = (Vector3.new(0, 1, 0) * Jump.JumpForce) + Vector3.new(ThrustForce.velocity.X, 0, ThrustForce.velocity.Z)
wait(0.1)
ThrustForce.maxForce = Vector3.new(ThrustForce.maxForce.X, 0, ThrustForce.maxForce.Z)
ThrustForce.velocity = Vector3.new(ThrustForce.velocity.X, 0, ThrustForce.velocity.Z)
Jump.LastJump = tick()
Jump.Jumping = false
end
elseif Key == "x" and Down then --Toggle light(s) on/off.
for i, v in pairs(Lights) do
if v and v.Parent then
v.Enabled = not v.Enabled
end
end
elseif Key == "h" and Down then --Play honk sound.
local Sound = Sounds.Honk
if (tick() - Honk.LastHonk) >= (Sound.TimeLength + Honk.ReloadTime) and not Honk.Honking then
Honk.Honking = true
local TempSound = Sound:Clone()
Debris:AddItem(TempSound, Sound.TimeLength)
TempSound.Parent = Body
TempSound:Play()
Honk.LastHonk = tick()
Honk.Honking = false
end
elseif Key == "q" and Down then --Activate special.
if not Special.Allowed or not Special.Enabled or Special.Active then
return
end
Special.Enabled = false
Special.Active = true
wait(Special.Duration)
Special.Active = false
wait(Special.ReloadTime)
Special.Enabled = true
elseif ByteKey == 48 and Down then --Activate speed boost.
if not SpeedBoost.Allowed or not SpeedBoost.Enabled or SpeedBoost.Active then
return
end
SpeedBoost.Enabled = false
SpeedBoost.Active = true
for i, v in pairs(Sparkles) do
if v and v.Parent then
v.Enabled = true
end
end
MaxSpeed.Acceleration = Speed.Acceleration.Boost
MaxSpeed.Deceleration = Speed.Deceleration.Boost
MaxSpeed.Movement = Speed.MovementSpeed.Boost
wait(SpeedBoost.Duration)
MaxSpeed.Acceleration = Speed.Acceleration.Normal
MaxSpeed.Deceleration = Speed.Deceleration.Normal
MaxSpeed.Movement = Speed.MovementSpeed.Normal
for i, v in pairs(Sparkles) do
if v and v.Parent then
v.Enabled = false
end
end
SpeedBoost.Active = false
wait(SpeedBoost.ReloadTime)
SpeedBoost.Enabled = true
end
end
end
end
function InvokeClient(Mode, Value)
local ClientReturn = nil
pcall(function()
ClientReturn = ClientControl:InvokeClient(Player, Mode, Value)
end)
return ClientReturn
end
Spawn(CleanUp)
ServerControl.OnServerInvoke = OnServerInvoke
Tool.Equipped:connect(Equipped)
Tool.Unequipped:connect(Unequipped)
```

Comment: could you try remvoing this? Humanoid.PlatformStand = false

Comment: I put the three dashes "---" in front to make it a comment incase it is not it. I played it and it still move the player to the middle of the map when unequipped. I took out both (commenting them) "Humanoid.PlatformStand = false" and "Humanoid.PlatformStand = true". It still didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it. Freezingplayer is the culprit. I took out "Spawn(FreezePlayer)" when it is unequipped and it works.

```
function Unequipped()
Spawn(CleanUp)
---Spawn(FreezePlayer)
```